# Angular JS : Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node' on HTMLScriptElement.callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using  Angular JSON Http call. in the same When I make the post request like this :

```
app.service('AjaxService', [ '$http','$q','$sce', function($http,$q,$sce) {
    return {
        getSearchResultsJSONP : function() {
            var url="http://stage-sp1004e4db.guided.lon5.atomz.com/?searchType=globalsearch&q=this&sp_staged=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
            $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
            $http.jsonp(url)
                .success(function(data) {
                console.log("Data for default SNP call" ,data);
            }).
            error(function (data) {
                console.log("request Failed ! ");
            });
        },
        getSearchResult : function(searchText,url){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: url, 
                method: "GET",
                params: {searchresInput: searchText}
            }).then(function(data, status, header, config){
                defer.resolve(data);

            }).then(function(data, status, header, config){
                defer.reject(data);

            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };

}]);
```

I can see the data in the network and response comes as 200 OK status.

But I am getting an error during complete code run :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined
    at checklistFunc (masterlowerlibs.67785a6….js:42972)
checklistFunc @ masterlowerlibs.67785a6….js:42972
```

can someone help me in the same, how to resolve this or what went wrong in the same ?

My response looks like :

```
angular.callbacks._0({metadata: {,…}, pagination: {totalpages: "1", firstpage: "", pagelinks: {pagelink: [,…]}},…})
facets
:
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
metadata
:
{,…}
pagination
:
{totalpages: "1", firstpage: "", pagelinks: {pagelink: [,…]}}
results
:
[,…]
sort
:
[{selected: true, name: "default", value: "relevance"}, {name: "Latest", value: "tkh_pageDate"}]
```

Comment: The error occurres in clicklistFunc in the masterlowerlibs file. I assume you wrote that part of the code. Would you also share that section?

Comment: do you have any javascript manipulations on the DOM element? like removing or adding a node?

Comment: I have No DOM manipulation in Javascript. One more Observation that I came across is that : I am using AEM in the project and when I use the page in a wcm edit mode this error occurs and when I use the page in wcm disabled mode this is not occuring. 

Also, When I use timeout in my JSONP call This error gets vanish, does this give any clue to you ?  @hakany

Comment: Your directive is trying to manipulate the DOM. But in between some other function is also doing the same. That's why it cant find the element it is looking for. When you do SetTimeout, you are able to space out the operations.

Comment: @vaibhav How are you calling your service?? can you show code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the error code line I assume you get the minified/obfuscated code, therefore I would suggest you to install and debug with AngularJS Batarang plugin for Chrome browser.

I hope this will help to understand why the error occurres.

Comment: Yes! I agree with this suggestion.